# Wordpress compromised but I do not know how

Tags: wordpress, security, spam, malware

today my Wordpress site was compromised so now serve a JS script that redirect to SPAM site.

I looked inside the Apache logs to reconstruct what happened, but i can't know how to interpretate this:

`xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:42 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:42 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:43 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:43 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:43 +0100] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 4 "/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:43 +0100] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 4 "/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:44 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4 "http://my.host.name/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:44 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 219966 "/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:47 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/theme-editor.php HTTP/1.1" 200 183974 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:48 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=404.php&theme=twentyfourteen HTTP/1.1" 500 3427 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [09/Jan/2017:10:24:49 +0100] "GET /wp-admin/theme-install.php?upload HTTP/1.1" 200 161448 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"`

As you can see somebody has tried to login, but he can't. But after two simple GET request to "/wp-admin/" seems to be logged in and he able to modify and install new theme.

At this point I have tried to find differences between the wp-admin directory that is present on the server with the original one downloaded from the official site wordpress.org, but i didn't find any differences. 
I compared all file present into wp-admin with "diff" utility and i can't find any difference. For example:
`diff /var/www/html/original.wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php /var/www/html.hacked/wp-admin/themes.php` didn't output any code

Could you help me to find evidence?

Comment: it show what error by frontend?

Comment: As a recomendation you can use https://wpscan.org/ to scan your wordpress

Comment: @mariobros On frontend there isn't any error, but only serve malicious JS to SPAM site.

Comment: @AlexanderCampos Wordpress Core, theme and plugins are update to latest version available

Comment: you can access to backend or is broken?

Comment: @mariobros Admin dashboard works correctly

Comment: so, could you try to update wp core even if everything update. Let me know

Comment: @mariobros i have just reinstalled Wordpress 4.7 correctly

Comment: @mariobros after correctly reinstall Wordpress 4.7 i can recreate what i see on acces log of Apache. On login page, if I use the admin username and a ANY password i can login without any problem. Absurd!!

Comment: never seen anything like this

Comment: install anti-malaware plugin and run a complete scan

Comment: You can try this WordPress plugin for securing your site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your exploit happened here:

/wp-admin/theme-install.php?upload

Make sure your themes and plugins are updated. That last request returned a 200 response from your webserver to the attacker, and was likely used to upload a backdoor. I'd audit the contents of /wp-content/uploads/ to see if there are any out of place PHP files (backdoor shells) in there. If so, it's possible they used that to pivot within your site, so there may be other directories containing PHP backdoors elsewhere.